# Rails 4: Action Mailer Unit Test - body of the email's actual string has unexpected line break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, actionmailer

When I run `rake test test:all` in my rails App I get the following failure:

```
NotificationsMailerTest#test_my_mails        
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-"Hello Kyle [John] Here is the information FROM THE APPLICATION! This is my email."
+"Hello Kyle [John] Here is the information FROM THE APPLICATION! This is my email.
+"
```

Notice that the endquote of the *actual* string is on another line.

The following represents the mailer test, and finally the view corresponding to the Mailer's
`send_application` function.

`notifications_mailer_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'

class NotificationsMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
    test "my mails" do
    # Send the email, then test that it got queued
    email = NotificationsMailer.send_application("This is my email.").deliver
    assert_not ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?
    # Test the body of the sent email contains what we expect it to
    assert_equal ['from@blag.net'], email.from
    assert_equal ['kyle@blag.net'], email.to
    assert_equal 'New Application', email.subject
    assert_equal "Hello Kyle [John] Here is the information FROM THE APPLICATION! This is my email.", email.body.to_s
   end
end
```

`send_application.text.erb`

```
Hello Kyle [John] Here is the information FROM THE APPLICATION! <%= @message%>
```

and here is my `NotificationsMailer`  and the corresponding `send_application` func:

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "from@blag.net"
  default :to => "kyle@blag.net"

  def send_application(body)
    @message = body 
    delivery_options = {
      user_name: "from@blag.net",
      password: "laowowtze",
      address: "secure3434.mostlator.com"
    }
    mail(:subject => "New Application")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your text editor added a new line at the end of the file `send_application.text.erb`.
You can also remove surrounding white spaces from body with `strip` method.

`assert_equal "Hello Kyle [John] Here is the information FROM THE APPLICATION! This is my email.", email.body.to_s.strip`